# Error in loading webui page of argocd there is no error in console or log file not sure how to debug the issue

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Argocd webui is not working as there only a white page visible .

As part of trouble shooting I restarted the service. did a patch upgrade .
Current: quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.4.9
New: quay.io/argoproj/argocd:v2.5.4

I tried to google for the solution for the above issue but couldnot find any solution to this issue.

> time="2023-03-08T09:45:11Z" level=error msg="Failed to walk extensions directory: failed to iterate files in '/tmp/extensions/': lstat /tmp/extensions/: no such file or directory"
> time="2023-03-08T09:46:18Z" level=info msg="received unary call /version.VersionService/Version" grpc.method=Version grpc.request.claims=null grpc.request.content= grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-03-08T09:46:18Z" span.kind=server system=grpc
> time="2023-03-08T09:46:18Z" level=info msg="finished unary call with code OK" grpc.code=OK grpc.method=Version grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-03-08T09:46:18Z" grpc.time_ms=16.593 span.kind=server system=grpc
> time="2023-03-08T09:46:22Z" level=info msg="received unary call /version.VersionService/Version" grpc.method=Version grpc.request.claims=null grpc.request.content= grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-03-08T09:46:22Z" span.kind=server system=grpc
> time="2023-03-08T09:46:22Z" level=info msg="finished unary call with code OK" grpc.code=OK grpc.method=Version grpc.service=version.VersionService grpc.start_time="2023-03-08T09:46:22Z" grpc.time_ms=12.958 span.kind=server system=grpc
> time="2023-03-08T09:50:27Z" level=error msg="Failed to walk extensions directory: failed to iterate files in '/tmp/extensions/': lstat /tmp/extensions/: no such file or directory"
> time="2023-03-08T09:52:53Z" level=info msg="Alloc=13866 TotalAlloc=79804 Sys=47185 NumGC=29 Goroutines=76"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cant find the error code. can you tell how to check